# Using cURL/OAuth to access del.icio.us api

Tags: php, api, curl, oauth, delicious-api

I'm following [this tutorial](http://delicious.com/help/oauthapi) to access the del.icio.us api, but this is my first time using cURL or OAuth so hitting a few snags.

I'm using the following code

```
    $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_nonce=123456789&oauth_timestamp="+$timestamp+"&oauth_consumer_key="+$consumerKey+"&oauth_signature_method=plaintext&oauth_signature="+$secret+"&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref=en-us&oauth_callback=http://www.chris-armstrong.com/paperclip");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);

$contents = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

according to the tutorial, this should return something like the following

> oauth_token%3Drpfbncv%26oauth_token_secret%3D5f2e792b36c40edaf7bdd8fb10b6edd1fde87a52%26oauth_expires_in%3D3600%26xoauth_request_auth_url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fapi.login.yahoo.com%252Foauth%252Fv2%252Frequest_auth%253Foauth_token%253Drpfbncv%26oauth_callback_confirmed%3Dtrue

but when I try to echo $contents, it returns blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out my main mistake was to use '+' instead of '.' to add different strings together. Also, the secret seems to require %26 after it, not sure why though.